# Python Selenium: hover over 'div' with 'onmouseover'

Tags: python, html, selenium, onmouseover

### Webpage View

[image: Picture of the webpage showing the menu]

### Webpage HTML Snippet

[image: Webpage HTML]

### Problem

I'm trying to use Python and Selenium to **scrape** this web site where the submenu shows after the mouse goes over the "Dossiê" menu.

### Attempt

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
action = ActionChains(browser)
(...)
action.move_to_element(browser.find_element_by_id('menuItem1')).perform()
```

When this code is run, a `NoSuchElementException` is raised. The element is found, but the `move_to_element` call doesn't show the submenu.

Comment: Is there any iframes prior to the element.

Comment: it will be much easier when you put real URL for this page instead of images.

Comment: Check to see you're not within an iframe. Also consider manually triggering the event if mouse over isn't working for you.

Comment: There's an iframe but I've allready switched to it. How can I manually trigger the event without hovering the mouse? It's a div. I can't click on it. Is there a way to force the onmouseover event of the javascript?

Comment: Your can driver.execute_script and call popmion.

Comment: Arundeep Chohan I'm not shure how to do this. I've tried:

browser.execute_script("arguments[0].popmion", browser.find_element_by_id('menuItem1'))


browser.execute_script("arguments[0].popmion", action.move_to_element(browser.find_element_by_id('menuItem1')))